# Display an html file with a custom css tag?

Tags: css, file, hyperlink, menu, src

I have a very large tree menu that will always be the same. Is it possible to create a custom css attribute (I don't know the technical term) so I can create the menu in an html file and only type a few characters in every page's source code to make the appear? Something like this:

// index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example of what I mean></title>
<link type="text/css" src="page_style.css" />
</head>

<div class="navigation_div">
<css_nav_thing><!-- Nav menu appears here --></css_nav_thing>
</div>

<div class="content_div">content stuff here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

// menu.html

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" src="nav_menu_style.css" />
<script src="nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<li>'s and <ul>'s that create the links for a navigation menu </li>'s and </ul>'s
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

// page_style.css

```
body {
   body stuff
}

css_nav_thing {
   src: (url="menu.html")
   position: stuff;
   margin: stuff'
   
}

.content_div {
   position: stuff;
   margin: stuff;
   andstuf: stuff;
}
```

// nav_menu_style.css

```
body {
   stuff: stuff;
]

a {
   color: #374;
   andstuff: stuff;
}
```

// content_page.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example of what I mean></title>
<link type="text/css" src="page_style.css" />
</head>

<div class="navigation_div">

<css_nav_thing>
<!-- Nav menu appears here -->
</css_nav_thing>

</div>

<div class="content_div">content stuff here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

// some_other_content_page.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Example of what I mean></title>
<link type="text/css" src="page_style.css" />
</head>

<div class="navigation_div">

<css_nav_thing>
<!-- Nav menu appears here -->
</css_nav_thing>

</div>

<div class="content_div">content stuff here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Or can we do this with a `<link src="menu.html" />` tag???
Is this possible to make adding the same menu to a bunch of pages easier than copy/pasting all of the menu's li's and ul's in to every single page? The site I'm building's going to have hundreds of pages. Hooray if I can make it easier and faster to do if this is possible!

If it is possible...how would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would name your menu menu.php then you can do below. This always works for me and you can always do this on any separated slides or gallery or whatever really you want to insert inside a particular page.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Example of what I mean></title>
<link type="text/css" src="page_style.css" />
</head>

<div class="navigation_div">

<--THIS IS WHERE YOUR MENU GO-->
          <?php include 'menu.php';?>
</div>

<div class="content_div">content stuff here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I haven't been working on websites since 2014. A lot has changed. The java/jquery/js and many other things I knew then seems long gone obsolete now. Do we still have to convert html to `<?php ?>`  with 'echo 'html tags' ' or is it possible to just change the file extension to php now?

Comment: this is a php if you want to use html you have to use a script for it, this is the easiest way for me. I call all my file as php then if you want to insert it you call it using <?php include ?>. You can always insert ths on your existing html page I dont think there will be an issue.

Comment: Tried it. 

Doesn't work.

Comment: I will try converting the html to php...will reply with the result in a few.

Comment: yeah try it. thats how i do it.

Comment: I converted index.html and menu.html to php format using an online converter. 
I'm running EasyPHP so I can work on php and other CMS packages and sites locally. The HTML version of the site loads fine with or without EasyPHP. The php version 404's. 
Does not work. I'm not positive I did everything correctly. I followed your short instructions. Input appreciated either way! Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure how are you doing it. Im the server im working on i usually change like this literally menu.html > menu.php then when i want to insert it in the page I call it <?php include 'menu.php';?>. Hope I can see what you are doing I will glad to help you out.

Comment: Are you changing index.html to index.php or leaving it as .html?

Comment: yes to index.php

Comment: I can't get this suggestion to work. I tried doing it many different ways. No go any way I tried doing it including the simple, short, explanation. Full example, please, if you will? Detailed step-by-step instruction...

Comment: if you are running it locally you have to run that to a local host like laragon which is a php compiler for it to work locally. If you are straight to your server that should work.

Comment: I use EasyPHP. Tried that. Didn't work.

Comment: Not sure what I did differently to get it to work but I got it working! Thank you very much, Crystal!!

Comment: Good to know you already figured it out. happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use Jquery

**menu.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" src="nav_menu_style.css" />
<script src="nav.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
<li>'s and <ul>'s that create the links for a navigation menu </li>'s and </ul>'s
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**some_other_content_page.html**

```
<html> 
  <head> 
   </head> 
<body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>

    //some_other_content_page.html content

 <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
 $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("menu.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

[Download Jquery](https://jquery.com/download/)

[.load() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: Is what you shared and `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>` all I need or do I need to spend weeks and months and years learning how to write jquery from the site you linked to write the `jquery.js` file?

Comment: Tried it. 

No go.